# What is this Groovy code doing?

Tags: groovy

I've been asked to hunt down a bug and believe I have tracked it down to the following line of Groovy code:

```
return (engine.calipers.every { it.make != null });
```

This corresponds to an `Engine` class that contains an instance variable `List<Caliper> calipers`. I **believe** this code will return `false` if an `Engine` instance contains a single `Caliper` that has a null `make` field value. But not being a Groovy guy, I wanted a second set of eyes to confirm this for me. Am I on track, or way off-base? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will return true if every `caliper` item's `make` member is not null; false otherwise.
But if any `caliper` item is null, it will throw a null pointer exception.